# Scala for comprehension with special treatment of empty list

Tags: scala, for-comprehension, empty-list

Is there a more functional way of doing the following?

```
if (myList.isEmpty) {
    println("Empty list")
} else for (element <- myList) {
    println(element)
}
```

Maybe something like:

```
for (element <- myList) {
    println(element)
} orElse {
    println("Empty list")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have seems fine, but one variation might be:

```
myList match {
  case Nil => println("Empty list")
  case _ => myList.foreach(println)
}
```

Comment: After a few months being exposed to Scala, I realized that we should avoid using if then else in the case that pattern matching can be applied. Pattern matching makes code more readable and concise. In addition, it provides higher flexibility due to the power of case class and apply() function in Scala.